# What is UITableViewCell setIndexBarWidth

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` which contains `UIImageView` and `UILabel`. The values for `UIImageView` and `UILabel` are taken from web service.

My problem is when I scroll the tableview down it shows error

`-[UITableViewCell _setIndexBarWidth:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x1681c470`

(only if Enabled Zombie Objects) and crashes. I googled but cannot find a single word about this error. The error not comes frequently. It may happens some time or may not. Also the error occurs only if internet is available. In offline mode everything works fine. 
Am using Xcode 5 with ARC.

Thank You...

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8298946/how-to-debug-message-sent-to-deallocated-instance-in-xcode4